# Error Propagation Calculation

Tags: bootstrap, error, error-propagation

I have a few machines that are used to calibrate each other.

Machine 1 has is accurate to 0.025%

Machine 1 is used to calibrate Machine 2, which has an accuracy of 0.005%

Machine 2 is used to calibrate Machine 3, which has an accuracy of 0.025%

Machine 3 is used to calibrate Machine 4, which has an accuracy of 0.04%

Using the root of the sum of the squares gives an error for Machine 4 of just over 0.052%, but I need it to be below 0.05%.  Is there any games I can play (like bootstrapping, maybe) to get this error down?

In other words, I can get all sorts of empirical calibration trials...Can I use that data somehow to bring down that error propagation?

Comment: machine 1 has worse accuracy than Machine 2, yet it's used to calibrate the latter?

Comment: Yes.  I don't like it either, but it's a matter of cost and size (machine 2 needs almost a crane to move, so sending it to be calibrated at a measurement facility is unfeasible).  Machine 1 can fit in a suitcase, and therefore is what is sent out to be calibrated at a measurement facility.

Comment: What's your data? is it measurements from Machine 5?

Comment: Yes...i can get measurement data from all machines

Comment: Then why do you have to measure with Machine 4? Why not measure it all with Machine 2? I think I'm missing something in your setup

Comment: Because we have hundreds of Machine 4.  Machine 2 is heavy and can't move, but it calibrates Machine 3 (which is portable), and that Machine 3 is used to calibrate several Machine 4's.

Comment: Got it. Is it true that you have a lot of Machine 4 measurements, fewer Machine 3, and even fewer Machine 2 measurements? Can you represent your sample in a table, where rows correspond to measured items, and columns to Machines? In this case rarely you have a row which is filled with data in all columns, but all rows have at least Machine 4 coulmn filled. Right?

Comment: Not quite...i have better access than that.  I can grab any machine and get as many independent measurements of it's error (according to the preceding Machine) off of it as needed.  In other words,  i can for instance, take machine 1&2 , and run them and then see what measurement error machine 2 had ACCORDING to machine 1....i can do this any number of times

Comment: However, you can't do Machine 1 and Machine 4 for the same sample? Basically, I don't understand why don't you calibrate Machine 4 with Machine 1.

Comment: Some of the reason is regulation driven, some is cost driven.  Machine 2 needs to be involved because of regulations and machine 3 needs to be calibrated by machine 2 for cost containment.  I wish it were different, but it's not in my control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely can't measure the same samples with Machine 1 and Machine 4, then I don't see what can be done here.

Machine 4's [precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) is going to be 0.04% no matter what. Its accuracy is going to be $\sqrt{0.025\%^2+0.005\%^2+0.025\%^2}=0.036\%$.

If you could measure the same sample with Machine 1 and 4, then you could adjust for the bias and increase accuracy, me thinks. You could increase accuracy to the precision of Machine 1 in this case.

UPDATE: The way I see this is that Machine 4 has a bias (accuracy) of ~0.036%, which was introduced by Machines 1-3. When you measure a sample with it, in average the mean will be at the bias level, while the dispersion (precision) will be 0.04%.

Machine 3 has both bias and precision ~0.025%. Since you can measure the same sample with 3 and 4, there has got to be a way to bring the accuracy of Machine 4 to that of Machine 3. Maybe you could compute an average difference between MAchine 4 and Machine 3 on a sub sample, then subtract it for all subsequent measurements of Machine 4, which would bring the accuracy up to ~0.025%. Again, I don't think anything can be done with a precision of Machine 4 (0.04%)

Comment: I see...How would we approach the last two sentences of your response?  It looks now like Machine 4 already has accuracy+precision upper bounds less than .04%.  I must have calculated that wrong.